# Rotating an item in layer-list for splash screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layer-list

I'm using

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
```

To make a splash screen. It's very fast, so I prefer it over layout system.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/login_blurry_bg"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:width="62dp"
    android:height="62dp">

            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="45"
                android:toDegrees="45"
                android:pivotX="-40%"
                android:pivotY="87%"
                android:drawable="@drawable/ic_progress_round"/>

</item>
```

I want to rotate this drawable on SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getWindow().getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash_background);

    RotateDrawable drawable = (RotateDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.progress);

    ObjectAnimator mAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(drawable, "level", 0, 10000);
    mAnimator.setDuration(300);
    mAnimator.start();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    finish();

}
}
```

But the animation is not working.

I also want a reveal transition while MainActivity opens. But that was not working too.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right);
```

Used this on the Splash Activity.

I think I'm doing something wrong. Help me with this please.

Comment: you should call this: overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right); after you call finish

Answer (score 0):

Please keep this code

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            },10000);
```

instead of these lines of code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

finish();
```

Above code would work but it's effect you could not see due to fast transition from Splace to Main activity.

You can set post delay millis value as per you feel okay.